# Validate file extension before upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to validate the file extension before upload so,I create the fileUpload control as following

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" OnChange="return validateFileExtension(this)"/>
```

and create java script to validate extension of file before upload

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var validFileExtensions = [".txt", ".TXT"];
function ValidateFileUpload(Source, args) {
var fuData = document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID%>');
var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;
if (FileUploadPath == '') {
// There is no file selected 
args.IsValid = false;
}
else {
var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
if (Extension == "txt" || Extension == "TXT") {
args.IsValid = true; // Valid file type
FileUploadPath == '';
 }
 else {
 alert("Please upload only text file")
 }
 }
 }
</script>
```

and I got 0x800a1391 - Javascript runtime error: 'validateFileExtension' is undefined

Comment: change `validateFileExtension()` to `ValidateFileUpload()` as `OnChange="return validateFileExtension(this)` accepts a function and `validateFileExtension()` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" OnChange="return ValidateFileUpload(this)"/>
```

`ValidateFileUpload` instead of `validateFileExtension`